# Data conversion to the correct format

Tags: json, pie-chart

We are using echarts of a website template now we are facing issue to pass data to pie chart,

Pie chart required data like in the following format
`[{ name : 'ABC', value : 0.00214585},{ name : 'XYZ', value : 0.00043364}, ...]`

But from backed we are getting json array and if we use json stringify then the data looks like
`[{"name":"NaNABC","value":0.00214585},{"name":"NaNXYZ","value":0.00043364}, ...]`

How to convert this data into correct format to feed into the pie chart?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your backend returning the data correctly? (i.e., why is there a `"name": "NaNABC"` in the response?

Comment: Yes the backend is returning data correctly, actually the backend is fetching the data from external API and passing it to the front, the API sends data in this format.